# How do I block all network access for a script?

Tags: python, c, sandbox

Suppose I have a script written in Python or Ruby, or a program written in C. How do I ensure that the script has no access to network capabilities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You more or less gave a generic answer yourself by tagging it with "sandbox" because that's what you need, some kind of sandbox. Things that come to mind are: using JPython or JRuby that run on the JVM. Within the JVM you can create a sandbox using a policy file so no code in the JVM can do thing you don't allow.

For C code, it's more difficult. The brute force answer could be to run your C code in a virtual machine with no networking capabilities. I really don't have a more elegant answer right now for that one. :)

Comment: Yup, decided to go with a VM. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using a sandboxed version of Python (using PyPy for example), there is no reliable way to switch-off network access from within the script itself.  Of course, you could run under a VM with the network access shut off.

Answer (score 0):

Firewalls can block specific applications or processes from accessing the network.  ZoneAlarms is a good one that I have used to do exactly what you want in the past.  So it can be done programatically, but I don't know near enough about OS programming to offer any advice on how to go about doing it.